# Magento is creating duplicate invoice ids for the orders

Tags: magento2, checkout, invoice, paypal-express, duplicate

When I checkout with paypal Express checkout , it shows error of duplicate invoice id. This is why we can not place order. Please help me.

Comment: Have you installed anything which modifies the increment ID syntax?

Answer (score 0):

**It's seems system try to create an invoice with same id again.**

Find the table `eav_entity_type` in database and check `entity_type_id` for entity_type_code have value invoice.

Now check table `eav_entity_store` in database and check `entity_type_id` which you got from above table for invoice

You will need to change `increment_last_id`. Also check store id reference for which you are getting this error.

Value should be greater than the last increment id of invoice created in your system.

Make one database backup before changing this in table.

Comment: Hello.... I have the same problem, and by changing Increment Id did not work... Magento always tries to use the same invoice number.